# how can i insert advanced data in spring boot test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, tdd

I'm making test code in spring boot.

But, my test code doesn't save the data using @Before method.

If i request to '/v1/stay/, it return empty array...

Please can you explain what is wrong with my code?

Here is my test code.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class StayControllerTest {
  @MockBean
  private StayService stayService;
  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  // givenStay method is the method generating dummy data
  @Before
  public void before() {
    stayService.save(givenStay1());
    stayService.save(givenStay2());
    stayService.save(givenStay3());
    stayService.save(givenStay4());
    stayService.save(givenStay5());
  }

    @Test
  @Transactional
  void showStayList() throws Exception {

    List<StayReq> original = new ArrayList<>();
    original.add(givenStay1());
    original.add(givenStay2());
    original.add(givenStay3());
    original.add(givenStay4());
    original.add(givenStay5());

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/v1/stay")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(print())
            .andReturn();

    System.out.println(result.getResponse());
  }
}
```

And below code blocks are my StayController and StayService

```java
@RestController
@ApiV1
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StayController {
  private final StayService stayService;
  private final ApiService apiService;

  @GetMapping("/stay")
  public ResponseEntity<Response> stayList() {
    return apiService.okResponse(stayService.getList());
  }
}
```

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StayService {
  private final StayRepository stayRepository;
  private final RoomRepository roomRepository;

  public List<StayRes> getList() {
    return stayRepository.findAll().stream().map(StayRes::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
  @Transactional
  public void save(StayReq stayReq) {
    stayRepository.save(stayReq.toEntity());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You injected a mock, not a 'real' service. If you want to use a 'real' service - you need to replace `@MockBean` annotation with `@Autowired` annotation.

Or alternatively - you can configure mock in the test method to return some predefined data.

Comment: thank you for your help and I apologize about late appreciation to you.